# Type error in read_csv() into the keyword

Tags: pandas, read-csv

Pandas in the read_csv() in  type error shown as:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 pd.read_csv('Datasets/BX-Books.csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1',error_bad_lines=False)

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
```

I have trying to run code is usaally in `error_bad_lines` parameter and run the code:

`pd.read_csv('Datasets/BX-Books.csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1',error_bad_lines=False)`

but  pandas old version is running and work  but why  do not work it and through error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 pd.read_csv('Datasets/BX-Books.csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1',error_bad_lines=False)

TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'error_bad_lines'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) this argument is deprecated and it was replaced by `on_bad_lines` argument. Here is the detail for this new argument :

**on_bad_lines**`{‘error’, ‘warn’, ‘skip’}` or Callable, default `‘error’`

Specifies what to do upon encountering a bad line (a line with too many fields). Allowed values are :

> `'error'`, raise an Exception when a bad line is encountered.
>
> `'warn'`, raise a warning when a bad line is encountered and skip that
> line.
>
> `'skip'`, skip bad lines without raising or warning when they are
> encountered.

So you can use this parameter instead, here is an example of using this parameter in your code :

```
pd.read_csv('Datasets/BX-Books.csv', sep=';',encoding='latin-1',on_bad_lines='skip')
```